# Installing PyMaxflow on Mac (boost issue)

Tags: boost, homebrew

I'm trying to install PyMaxflow on a Mac (Mavericks) which requires boost. I have boost with homebrew installed but the build file still can't find it. Any thoughts?

```
In file included from maxflow/src/_maxflow.cpp:317:
In file included from maxflow/src/fastmin.h:11:
In file included from maxflow/src/core/graph.h:48:
In file included from maxflow/src/core/../pyarray_index.h:5:
maxflow/src/pyarraymodule.h:12:10: fatal error: 'boost/mpl/clear.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/mpl/clear.hpp>
     ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
rrdhcp-10-33-45-150:PyMaxflow david$ open /usr
rrdhcp-10-33-45-150:PyMaxflow david$ open /usr
rrdhcp-10-33-45-150:PyMaxflow david$ brew install boost
Warning: boost-1.55.0 already installed
rrdhcp-10-33-45-150:PyMaxflow david$
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run setup.py install, you need to make sure the setup.py file has the correct path to your boost directory. If you open the file, you'll see a line as follows:

maxflow_module[0].include_dirs.append(numpy_include_dir)

That pretty much includes all your "include" directories:-) To include your boost directory correctly, you just need to add:

maxflow_module[0].include_dirs.append(r"$yourboostdirectory")

Comment: Make sure it is the directory containing the boost directory. In my case it was `/opt/local/include/`